# UITableView emerge from right on UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to make my first animation. Currently I'm using `animateWithDuration:animations` and `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:`, but I'm not sure if I'm in "correct page".

What I want to do is to create such animation: in the left upper corner user taps on button and `UITableView` arrives from the left side of the screen.

I never did any animation in iOS SDK so any help will be appreciated: similiar problems in StackOverflow, some tutorials etc. I don't know where should I begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have a UITableView as subview of a UIViewController's view.

First, before the animation, set the UITableView out of the screen, use center or frame property:

```
CGRect screenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
self.theTableView.frame = CGRectMake(-screenFrame.size.width, 0.0, screenFrame.size.width, screenFrame.size.height);
```

Then, complete the animation code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                         self.theTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, screenFrame.size.width, screenFrame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:nil];
```

Hope it will help you! :D